# Rendering special characters in readonly input field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-encode

In ASP.NET MVC application i'm using `TagBuilder` to create readonly input field.

```
public class DisplayTextFieldBuilder<TModel, TProperty>
{
    private HtmlHelper<TModel> _helper;
    private Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> _expression;

    public DisplayTextFieldBuilder(HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        _helper = helper;
        _expression = expression;            
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {        

        var id = _helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(_expression));
        var name = _helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(_expression));

        var value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_helper.DisplayFor(_expression).ToString());         

        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        builder.MergeAttribute("value", value);
        builder.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        builder.MergeAttribute("name", name);            
        builder.MergeAttribute("readonly", "readonly");                        

        var html = builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);            

        return html;
    }
```

However certain string does not render properly. For example, lets say the model property value is **Foe`s BBQ** (note it has apostrophe)
then

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_helper.DisplayFor(_expression).ToString())
```

renders this value as `Foe&amp;#39;s, BBQ`

if i remove html encoding  then

```
 _helper.DisplayFor(_expression).ToString()
```

renders this value as `Foe&#39;s, BBQ`

what i am missing?

Comment: Why are you doing this? You can just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourProperty, new { @readonly = "readonly" })` And if you do want to create a `HtmlHelper` extension method, then this is not the way to do it.

Comment: The `HtmlHelper` approach looks overkill for me. A simple readonly assignment with `@readonly = "readonly"` is enough, and it also can render apostrophe text provided from GET controller (tried in a fiddle).

Comment: we have created fluent interface for all our controls. So developer does have to remember class, styles they have to to use. Constancy!. (something along the line of Telerik's Kendo for ASP.NET MVC). and now if we have to change something it only one place to change. For brevity i didn't write all the code above